# Ternary Operator streamlining

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am a Javascript beginner and I am completing some challenges. The challenge is to design a function using two arguments (name, language) that outputs a greeting in the chosen language in this format: "Hello, Bob!", also using the English greeting as the default.

I have chosen a ternary operator to execute this task, however the code seems large and clunky. Is there a way I could streamline this? perhaps to have a console.log statement of language + name + "!" ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Code below

```
  return language === "english" ? 'Hello, ' + name + "!" :
  language === "czech" ? 'Vitejte, ' + name + "!":
  language === "danish" ? 'Velkomst, ' + name + "!":
  language === "dutch" ? 'Welkom, ' + name + "!":
  language === "estonian" ? 'Tere tulemast, ' + name + "!":
  language === "finnish" ? 'Tervetuloa, ' + name + "!":
  language === "flemish" ? 'Welgekomen, ' + name + "!":
  language === "french" ? 'Bienvenue, ' + name + "!":
  language === "german" ? 'Willkommen, ' + name + "!":
  language === "irish" ? 'Failte, ' + name + "!":
  language === "italian" ? 'Benvenuto, ' + name + "!":
  language === "latvian" ? 'Gaidits, ' + name + "!":
  language === "lithuanian" ? 'Laukiamas, ' + name + "!":
  language === "polish" ? 'Witamy, ' + name + "!" : 
  language === "spanish" ? 'Bienvenido, ' + name + "!":
  language === "swedish" ? 'Valkommen, ' + name + "!":
  language === "welsh" ? 'Croeso, ' + name + "!" :
  "hello"
}
```

Comment: For this singular case, one option would be to use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement. For the more generic case of translating, maps from language and message id to a translated string are often used.

Comment: The `switch` statement would be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: Don't use the conditional operator at all. Instead, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of languages-to-greetings. (Or a `switch`, but for me `Map` would be the better choice. Less boilerplate code.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, switch case is best here as already Etheryte and tromgy are commented the same.

- Check the below sample code for your reference.
- This code is tested and it's working fine.

```js
var language = "language1";
var name = "PALNATI";
switch(language)
{
     case "language1":
     console.log("Your_Geeting1, "+name+"!");
     break;
     case "language2":
     console.log("Your_Geeting2, "+name+"!");
     break;
     
     default:
     console.log("Your_GeetingXYZ, "+name+"!");
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could have an object containing all of the language keys, for example

```
const welcomeTranslations = {
    "english": "Hello",
    "czech": "Vitejte"
    //and so on...
}
console.log(`${welcomeTranslations[language]}, ${name}!`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a an object to map each language to its own greeting then create a greet function which concatenates the elements into a sentence based on the given language and name.

Note that the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator%22) acts as a fallback, if the language was not found in the map, it wall fall back to "Hello".

```js
const greetings = {
  english: "Hello",
  czech: "Vitejte",
  danish: "Velkomst",
  dutch: "Welkom",
  estonian: "Tere tulemast",
  finnish: "Tervetuloa",
  flemish: "Welgekomen",
  french: "Bienvenue",
  german: "Willkommen",
  irish: "Failte",
  italian: "Benvenuto",
  latvian: "Gaidits",
  lithuanian: "Laukiamas",
  polish: "Witamy",
  spanish: "Bienvenido",
  swedish: "Valkommen",
  welsh: "Croeso",
};

function greet(name, language) {
  return `${greetings[language] ?? "Hello"}, ${name}!`;
}

console.log(greet("John", "english"));
console.log(greet("Juan", "spanish"));
console.log(greet("Johan", "swedish"));
console.log(greet("Captain sweatpants", "klingon")); // falls back to english
```